# What is causing my game to have really low fps

Tags: python, pygame

ok so i just finished a simple game i made in python and pygame and on my laptop im only getting 9 fps. So it must be my code. I am new to game programming. I think it is the way i animate my sprites thats causing the fps drop.
If you guys could take a look at my sorce code that would be great. sorry for the bad programming

http://www.mediafire.com/download/7f4q55gk4a853o7/Life+of+Bob.zip

Comment: Have you tried profiling? Profiling is probably the fastest way to find the big hotspots and improve performance. If you dont know about this, just google python profiling. This question is too broad if you dont have anything more specific, because you are essentially asking for a service on your whole codebase. See also these tips: https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/newbieguide.html

Comment: ty sorry for the bad question il look up profileing

Answer (score 3):

I took a look at your code and found the solution in changing line 392 inside the `__init__` method of your `Map` object from

```
self.currentmap = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "maps", "spawn.png"))
```

to

```
self.currentmap = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "maps", "spawn.png")).convert()
```

If you have images that don't need an alpha channel you should always call `convert` on them.

At the beginning I had a framerate of 18 fps now it's the desired 60 fps.

The key tool to find this bottleneck was the python module [`cProfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html). Next time you should learn about it before posting a wall of nearly 500 lines of code .

Also consider changing the loading of your image files to the initialization of your objects into a list. Currently you are loading all the images for your characters each time you render them.

Comment: thanks alot i know my question was kinda dumb and my code was really bad. i really appreciate you taking the time to look at my question and code